# GWT - celltable

Tags: gwt

I'm having problem with a column in my cell table not being populated with anything. Following is my code:

```
public class CellTableExample implements EntryPoint {

private static class Contact 
{
    private String address; 
    private String name;
    private String phone="";

    public Contact(String name, String address, String phone) {
        super();
        this.address = address; 
        this.name = name; 
        this.phone=getPhoneNumber(name);
    } 
}
public String getPhoneNumber(String name)
{
    String pNum="";
    SQLRunnerAsync service = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String[]> result)
        {
            pNum=reuslt;
        }
    };
    service.findPhoneNum(name,callback);
    return pNum;
}


// The list of data to display.
  private static List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
    new Contact("John", "123 Fourth Road asdf asdf asdfasdf"),
    new Contact("Mary", "222 Lancer Lane")

  );

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>(); 

    SQLRunnerAsync service = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
    AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String[]>  result)
        {
            compFlexTable.setPageSize(result.size());

            Contact[] contactArr = new Contact[result.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
            {       
                String [] temp = result.get(i);
                String name=temp[0];//name
                String address=temp[1];//address


                contactArr[i]=new Component1(name,address);
            }
            COMPONENT=Arrays.asList(compArray);


    //address column
    TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>(){
        @Override
        public String getValue(Contact contact) {
            return contact.address;
        }
    };

    //name column
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>(){
        @Override
        public String getValue(Contact contact) {
            return contact.name;
        }
    };

            //name column
    TextColumn<Contact> phoneColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>(){
        @Override
        public String getValue(Contact contact) {
            return contact.phone;
        }
    };
    service.getContactInfo(callback);

    // Add the columns.
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
    table.addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

    table.setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);
    table.setRowData(0, CONTACTS);

    RootPanel.get().add(table); 
}
```

}

So when I'm creating a contact object, another async method is being called to get the phone number for the contact. The table displays fine but the column for the phone number is empty. How do I resolve this? Any ideas/suggestions will be appreciated.. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the order of execution of your program.  In getPhoneNumber, you set pNum to "", start an asynchronous request, and then return pNum.  pNum is still "" at the end of this process.  Later, when your asynchronous request returns, pNum is set to `result`, but at that point it's too late - your celltable has already been rendered.

Basically, you can't expect any asynchronous calls to complete in time to render your table accurately, once render has been called.  All of the data you need must be immediately available before you render, or it won't show up.  You can subclass a DataProvider to do these extra retrievals before asking the CellTable to render itself.

Answer (score 0):

use asynchronous data provider   as @Riley  said

for more reference use the below link ..

http://www.mytechtip.com/2010/11/gwt-celltable-example-using_8168.html